# What is Liberal Democracy?

Tags: united-kingdom

The Liberal Democrats are a social-liberal supporting party in the United Kingdom. The third largest party in the UK  is the Liberal Democrats.This is because of number of seats in the quarters of Commons and number of councillors. Liberal democracy history is a history of formation of administration in which delegate democracy operate under the principle of liberalism.

Answer (score 3):

Liberal democracy is the combination of a democratic system (in which policy is ultimately determined through popular elections) and liberalism (in which the state has limited control over the individual, and there are strong protections for civil liberties). In a liberal democracy, people are generally free to do what they like, even if that involves criticizing the government; the government doesn't get to control society, suppress opposition, or do whatever they please (the government is bound by laws just like the citizens are).

There's also a limit on what a majority is able to do to a minority; this may be formal (e.g. the US Bill of Rights) or informal (e.g. the UK, where Parliament can technically pass any law it wants but in practice *won't* pass laws like "members of `$disfavored_minority` are stripped of citizenship and all their stuff may be taken by anyone else"). If informal pressure, either social pressure or government pressure, means that people can't generally express opposing political views, then that's a sign that you aren't in a liberal democracy.

The definition is sort of fuzzy; it's basically a way of excluding countries that have elections but severely restrict political opposition (and so, in practice, it's a bad idea from a personal safety perspective to express views that the government doesn't like, or to go against the majority). The point of a liberal democracy is that you're generally free to hold whatever views you want and spread those views without fear. A number of countries technically have democratic elections but in practice don't have generally free and open political debate.

However, you should know that this has precisely nothing to do with the Liberal Democrats in the UK. The Liberal Democrats are so named because they're the result of a merger between the Liberal Party and the Social Democratic Party. The best combination of the names was "Liberal Democrats."

Comment: re: *won't pass laws like "members of $disfavored_minority are stripped of citizenship and all their stuff may be taken by anyone else"* - tell that to France - supposedly a liberal democracy - where they happily passed the law that members of $disfavored_minority (uber rich) have MOST of their stuff (90% income) taken by anyone else. Granted, the citizenship issue was vice versa, where they **criticized** said minority who wanted to leave.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a “liberal democracy” is the kind of democracy you are familiar with. After World War II, the Soviet Union theorized that the countries under its influence represented [another kind of democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_democracy_(Marxism%E2%80%93Leninism)) (which most people in the West, even some Marxists, Trotskyists and obviously Anarchists, would not consider a democracy at all), hence the need of a word to distinguish the two.

As @cpast already explain, this has very little to do with the UK “Liberal Democrats”.